# Can Firebug Lite be loaded conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, firebug-lite

I'd like to be able to load Firebug lite conditionally (eg, based on the value of debug variable). I've tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var fileref; 

    if(condition) {
        fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js")
    }

</script>
```

at the top of my `<head>`, but to no avail. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You have created the element, but forgot to insert it into the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating an element, you need to insert it into the DOM. This can be done using `.appendChild()`.

Add this to your `if`:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
head.appendChild(fileref);
```

Comment: Brilliant, that did it. Thanks. I mistakenly thought the createElement method did this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your footer. I'm open to criticism. If you can make this better, go for it.

```
<script>

        // First uncomment this to get your user agent, 
        // So we can hide Firebug Lite from the general public
        // Remember to change this if you change browsers :-)
        // document.write("<p>User agent: "+ navigator.userAgent +"</p>");

        // Note: Not sure why but Firebug Lite may open in a new tab, even if you tell it not to 
        // UNLESS you use Google Chrome for Android (NOT the Beta version!) 

        if (
            navigator.userAgent == "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2;"
        ) 
        {    
            var fileref; 
            fileref=document.createElement("script");
            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");

            // Pick your version here https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite
            fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://fbug.googlecode.com/svn/lite/branches/firebug1.4/content/firebug-lite-dev.js");

            // Add to DOM
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
            head.appendChild(fileref);
        }

        /* Defaults (supposedly)
        saveCookies - false
        startOpened - false
        startInNewWindow - false
        showIconWhenHidden - true
        overrideConsole - true
        ignoreFirebugElements - true
        disableXHRListener - false
        disableWhenFirebugActive - true
        enableTrace - false
        enablePersistent - false
        */

    </script>
```

Comment: If it wasn't obvious, I used Dvir's answer but added some things.